# Is it possible to Update the table values which contains multiple criteria using single update statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle11g

```
Table

ID    DESC
1     Male
2     Male
3     Male
4     Female
5     Female
6     Female
7     Female
```

I need to update the male to female and female to male using one update statement.Kindly advice on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UPDATE Table
SET DESC  = CASE 
    WHEN DESC= 'Male' THEN 'Female'
    WHEN DESC  = 'Female' THEN 'Male'
    ELSE DESC        
  END
```

out put as follow

```
ID    DESC

1     Female
2     Female
3     Female
4     Male
5     Male
6     Male
7     Male
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server

```
update tbl
SET DESC  = CASE 
    WHEN DESC= 'Male' THEN 'Female'
    WHEN DESC  = 'Female' THEN 'Male'
    ELSE DESC        
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do that using **case** statement

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET DESC = CASE WHEN DESC = 'MALE' THEN 'Female' WHEN DESC = 'Female' THEN 'MALE' ELSE DESC END
```